# MS Edge Developer Tools Emulator not working

Tags: developer-tools, microsoft-edge

Changing the "User agent string" in MS Edge Developer Tools Emulator just makes the page refresh. For example, if I change it to Internet Explorer 6, the page refreshes but all my CSS3 properties still display as if I'm in a modern browser. Flexbox, 3D transitions and transforms all continue to work.

Comment: Does your server return different page, depending on "User agent string"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edge is not emulating old versions of IE, the way that you could in old versions of IE. That is because all of the old rendering engines have been removed. What you are changing just changes the user-agent string sent to servers, and nothing else. Unless you are serving different content based on user-agents server side, there should be no difference.